# Score total from previous levels

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, text

I am trying to have a fresh score for each level but have them all added into a grand total at the end.
I am using states in the engine to change levels and a new movie clip and class for each level but the scoring is the same and the names of the ScoreCounter.

I would also like the player to choose their 2 favorite levels at the end to multiply the scores of both by two but that is way beyond me.

In the loop I have

```
scoreCount.text = String(score);
```

and for scoring points

```
if ( currentKey is Up && upKey )
{
    score += scoreBonus;

    currentKey.active = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, if I don't explain it well enough then look up some tutorials on custom events and shared objects.

You could save the scores to a shared object (flash cookie)

If you have a custom event dispatched for next level or level won etc then you can save the score then (make your custom event have a score variable that is updated when called). If you aren't using custom events then you should have a look at some tutorials, they're handy.

Anyway, to add a score parameter to your events

```
public class YourEvent extends Event {

    public var lvlScore:int;
    public static const NEXT_LEVEL:String = "Next Level";

    public function YourEvent( type:String, score:int ) {

        super( type );
        lvlScore = score;
    }
}
```

Have a look at custom events!

To save the scores using a shared object:

At the top of the .as

```
private var sharedObj:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal( "YourGame" );
```

To get/set the score just use

```
sharedObj.data.level1Score
```

To check if it exists

```
if( sharedObj.data.level1Score )
```

Good Luck!